# JQuery Accordion collapsing rows

Tags: jquery

I am not a jQuery expert,  but I have  2 rows of accordions collapsed by default with icon based service tabs, all is loading and working ok apart from...

If a user has opened row 1 and then clicks an icon in row 2 it should close row 1 before opening row 2 (and vice versa of course).  At the moment it opens row 2 without closing row 1.

If you click an icon in either row it will close itself so that part is working ok. I am showing you the code that is in use and hope some one can point out what is missing.
Apologies in advance for something probably pretty obvious but I am missing it.

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs-services-row1, #tabs-services-row2").tabs({/*,#tabs-services-row3,#tabs-  services-row4*/
        collapsible: true,
        active: 'false', //none
        selected: -1,
        fx: { height: 'toggle', duration: 'normal' }
    });
    return false;

    $("#tabs-services-row1 ul.toptabs li a").click (function(){
         $( "#tabs-services-row2" ).tabs('option', 'selected', -1);
    });

    $("#tabs-services-row2 ul.toptabs li a").click (function(){
        $("#tabs-services-row1,").tabs('option', 'selected', -1);
    });


    $("#tabs-services-row1.tab-pane a.btn-tabs-services-close").click (function(){
        $( "#tabs-services-row1" ).tabs('option', 'selected', -1);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: A sample of your html would be helpful. A fiddle would be ideal. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you using jQuery's accordion? I don't see the `.accordion()`. Some sample HTML would be good too.

Comment: Interesting this actually works ok in jffiddle and from VS2010. It looks like a conflict in the DNN cms we are using.
A bit more investigation is needed before posting back.